# Completing a given SQL statement so that another column is displayed in the end

Tags: sql, multiple-columns

I'm given the following statement:

```
SELECT id FROM record_database WHERE id = <up to me to complete the statement>
```

The record database has different fields, among which are id and name.

I'm supposed to complete this select statement so that it displays all the ids and all the corresponding names side by side, and this should be done using this one line of SQL code. A hint was given that UNION or OR can be used.

I tried variations of the following:

```
SELECT id FROM record_database WHERE id = '*'
UNION
SELECT name FROM record_database WHERE name = '*';
```

But none of these worked. I tried doing this with AND, tried using display columns, but those didn't work either.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What do you mean side by side on the same line? Do you mean two different columns or two columns into one column?

Comment: I have to complete this one line of SQL code so that the two columns are diplayed side by side.

Answer (score 1):

This smells a great deal like homework, so I won't offer a complete answer, but you can't just union queries that return dissimilar result sets. I'm inferring that ID is an integer while NAME is some varchar, which won't union as you've listed in your hint.

When you say "complete," are you restricted to adding things to the end? If so, its a non-starter. You can't increase the list of fields being returned merely by adding things to the "WHERE" clause. You need to add things to the actual field list to get them to be returned, so you  might clarify whether you are truly restricted to appending to the query you;ve given.

Comment: It is homework, and yup I am restricted to just this line of code. But I can add whatever I want to the end, so I'm assuming there's a way to add another select statement to the end that will display the name column. Also assume id and name are the same type.

Comment: Then I'm going to stand by my original assertion. The fields returned in a SELECT statement are those constrained in the field list, and if you can't adjust the field list, and must add things only to the end, you *cannot* create a two-column output. There are all manner of tricks you might apply, but even those imply putting things in the *front* of the query, which is still against the rules as you're explaining them...

Comment: No putting things in front of the query is perfectly fine, I can literally put whatever I want after that = sign.

Comment: Ahh, okay, if you can *prepend* things to it, that *may* open some other avenues..

Comment: Oh sorry, no I can't put things before the statement, just after.

Comment: Harumph. :) Constraining you to the WHERE clause is a killer. Are you absolutely certain the expectation is a two-column table result?

Comment: I think that's what it should be ideally, but if I can at the very least get names to display, that would count for something. Even if it just appends it to the end of one column, as they are all of the same type (varchar).

Comment: Is the ID field numeric, and is the NAME varchar?

Comment: Aha, okay, then you should at least be able to make a union work, albeit not side by side. :)

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking for:

```
id
name
id next
name next
```

Then use this trick:

```
SELECT col2 
FROM (
    SELECT id, col2=convert ( varchar (size of name field),id) 
    FROM table 
    WHERE ....

    UNION ALL

    SELECT id, name 
    FROM table 
    WHERE ....
     ) 
ORDER BY id
```

This `order by` will bring id and name side by side and col2 will contain id in first row and name in second row.

Answer (score 1):

Cheating. Make the select return 0 rows and add another one that will show 2 columns. All in one and the same line:

```
SELECT id FROM record_database WHERE id = NULL;SELECT id,name FROM record_database;
```

No more time should be wasted on silly problems like this.

---

If both `id` and `name` are char (or varchar), you could also do this, concatting the two columns into one:

```
SELECT id FROM record_database WHERE id = NULL
UNION ALL
SELECT id || '--' || name FROM record_database ;
```

The `id || '--' || name` part differs from one DBMS to another. In some, the `+` is the concat operator, in others there are special functions. So you may need to use:

```
id  + '--'  + name
```

or:

```
CONCAT(id, '--', name)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
SELECT * FROM record_database WHERE id = '*' OR name = '*'
```

Comment: I know that select id, name would allow for both columns to be displayed, but the trick here is that I have to use the statement given, which does not have the ", name" part in it.

Comment: Nope that doesn't work, because I can't select *, as I'm confined to what is given. Worth noting that I tried something similar to this earlier along with the union I gave above, in both cases I do get a list of the ids, but the name column is never there.